# How to use a Service Request as generic

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am trying to make a function which accepts a Service Request of any type, so something like this:

```
template<typename T, typename ServiceT>
```

```
bool sendRequest(std::shared_ptr> client, std::shared_ptr request);
```

The first parameter works fine, but the second parameter does not work, and I'm not sure how to do it correctly.
How do I use the generic for a Service Request?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/393591/how-to-use-a-service-request-as-generic/) by [xander-m2k](https://answers.ros.org/users/89228/xander-m2k/) on ROS Answers with karma: 23 on 2021-12-31

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You're close! First, the template typenames **T** and **ServiceT** are the same types, so you only need to declare one, let's use **ServiceT**.

You did not specify why "the second parameter does not work", so it's impossible to know for sure what your issue is... The following could work:

```
template <typename ServiceT>
bool sendRequest(std::shared_ptr<rclcpp::Client<ServiceT>> client, std::shared_ptr<typename ServiceT::Request> request)
{
    // let 'node' be a std::shared_ptr<NodeType> declared elsewhere...
    auto result = client->async_send_request(request);
    return rclcpp::FutureReturnCode::SUCCESS == rclcpp::spin_until_future_complete(node, result);
}
```

The difference for the second argument is the **typename** keyword. Since this is a templated function, the compiler needs to know that for any **ServiceT**, that ServiceT::Request will be a type name. Without the typename keyword, the compiler doesn't have enough information to know your intention, e.g. ServiceT::Request could be a static data member.

In the future, you should at least include why "the second parameter does not work".

---

Originally posted by [rnvandemark](https://answers.ros.org/users/45301/rnvandemark/) with karma: 36 on 2021-12-31

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [xander-m2k](https://answers.ros.org/users/89228/xander-m2k/) on 2022-01-03**:
I'm sorry for describing a vague description of it not working. I knew the syntax was not correct, hence I simply said "it does not work", but actually it should be "incorrect syntax".

Anyway, I think this does work indeed.
My goal was to make the function more intuitive for the user, so the functions second parameter would only be used with a request, because `async_send_request()` uses that as parameter. Apart from that, my first idea was to leave it just as `std::shared_ptr<ServiceT> request`, because I did not know how to do that.

I'm actually wondering how this works. For the first parameter it seems simple, because ServiceT will just be any type of the class `rclcpp::Client`. But, for the second argument, since ServiceT is not an actual type, how does the compiler know that the ServiceT type has a Request type, and how would that match against the actual Request class? Is the name of the typename the part that matters most for this? How does that work?